# Tensorflow tuples with different shapes

Tags: python, tensorflow, factorization

I have a problem with returning a tuple of two variable `v` , `wt` where `v` has `shape=(20,20)` and `wt` has `shape=(1,)`. `wt` is a variable that is a weight value. I  want to return the tuple (v,wt) inside a `map_fn`

my code look somewhat close to this

```
tf.map_fn(fn, nonzeros(Matrix, dim, row))

nonzeros(Matrix, dim, row) returns a (index, value)
```

the `fn` will return a tuple but the error output I get is :

```
ValueError: The two structures don't have the same number of elements. First 
structure: <dtype: 'int64'>, second structure: (<tf.Tensor 
'map_2/while/while/Exit_1:0' shape=(20,) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 
'map_2/while/Sub:0' shape=() dtype=int64>).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning the results of a `tf.while` loop here. the `tf.while` loop returns a tuple of multiple values, in your case we can see that your while loop returned a value of interest and a counter value as a tuple.

```
(<tf.Tensor 'map_2/while/while/Exit_1:0' shape=(20,) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'map_2/while/Sub:0' shape=() dtype=int64>)
```

What you mean to pass back from `map_fn` is probably just the first of these two values. So in the code that you haven't shown here you should have something like:

```
value, counter = tf.while(...)
return value
```

What you have is:

```
return tf.while(...)
```

So the error you see is complaining that an `<dtype: 'int64'>` doesn't match the `tuple` you're passing in. When you fix the while loop then you'll be comparing `<dtype: 'int64'>` to `<tf.Tensor 'map_2/while/while/Exit_1:0' shape=(20,) dtype=float32>` which presumably are both (20,) and will match (though you might end up with an int/float issue).